# test-connection searchbase No such host is known

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run something so basic, that it's somewhat embarrassing to be asking...
...anyways, hopefully, someone will point it out and roastme. ;-)

```
$PCs = Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase "OU=Domain servers,DC=company,DC=com"

foreach ($PC in $PCs)

{
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC -Count 1)
{
write-host "online and do this" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor White
}
else {
    {
}
write-host "offline and skip doing this" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor White
}
}
```

I keep getting the error per entry:

**Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'CN=svr1,OU=Servers,OU=Domain Servers,DC=company,DC=com' failed: No such host is known**

I know I've done this before "successfully", but I'm doing some late-night stuff and hoping to see something soon.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem:

Change this:
`if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC -Count 1)`

For this:
`if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC.Name -Count 1)`

**Edit:** Without calling the property Name, Test-Connection is using the position 0 of each object (DistinguishedName) as input parameter.

The error itself is because DNS can't resolve DN to IP, hence why you need to pass the Name or fully qualified domain name of the computer you want to ping.

Comment: Add `-Quiet` to return a boolean value so the `if` condition can evaluate it properly. Currently itll still run the first `do`, regardless of what it returns because it returns something.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could explain why changing that would resolve the issue.